# XML tag labels in Python

Tags: python, xml

Here's an example of some data in an XML file I have to retrieve with Python:

```
<Temperatures>
    <Temperature units="C" tc_type="T" index="0" input_id="2" data_source="0" type="THERMOCOUPLE"     description="TC2 outlet right degC" value="1.054109E+02"/><Temperature units="C" tc_type="T" index="1" input_id="3" data_source="0" type="THERMOCOUPLE" description="TC3 inlet left degC" value="1.070252E+02"/>
</Temperatures>
```

When I use this code:

```
for elem in tree.iter(tag='Temperature'):
```

it does what I want. If I use "tag='Temperatures'", which is what the tag really is, it doesn't work. Why does it force me to ignore the 's' at the end of 'Temperatures'?

Comment: The element Temperatures contains an element Temperature. This one without the s has the attributes - so why do you think the one with the s is the correct tag?

Comment: What does tree.tag say? You are likely already on the `Termperatures` element and are looking at its children.

Comment: Which of the several xml processors are you using?

Comment: I loaded your doc into lxml. Iterating "Temperatures" produced 1 element. Iterating "Temperature" produced 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
for elem in tree.iter(tag='Temperature')
```

It is as if you said, in plain English

```
loop over each tag named 'Temperature' contained in tree
```

And then you have the results you want because `tree` contains such tags and **they have the desired attributes**.

On the other hand, if you write

```
loop over each tag named 'Temperatures' contained in tree
                                     ^
```

It won't work because if it's true that there is at least one tag named `Temperatures` in `tree`, **this/these tag(s) contain(s) other tags, but no attributes**. You would have to loop over it to find each `Temperature` tag anyway to retrieve the attributes you need.

Comment: The original xml clearly does have a tag named `Temperatures`.

Comment: Thanks, I see what it's doing now that you explain it.